# How to use TA-Lib with Google App Engine Flexible Python?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, ta-lib

From my research you can't use Google App Engine Standard Environment for [TA-Lib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) python wrapper because it uses C-Extensions? You have to use Flexible Environment.

To use TA-Lib python wrapper, you would add it to the dependency file `requirements.txt` in your app engine flexible project. The documentation however says "To use TA-Lib for python, you need to have the main [TA-Lib](http://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html) already installed"

How would you add this main TA-Lib to your app engine flexible project so you can use the TA-Lib python wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added the main TA-Lib to my flexible project and added the TA-Lib python wrapper to requirements file. I also had to add numpy to requirements:

```
flexible_project
  |
  +--ta-lib
  +--app.yaml
  +--main.py
  +--requirements.txt
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do this so please answer with better way if you have one